# ng2-dnd with Angular 4

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drag

I'm trying to implement drag & drop (https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) in Angular project.

My config (`ng -v`):

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.3
node: 6.10.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.4
@angular/common: 4.2.4
@angular/compiler: 4.2.4
@angular/core: 4.2.4
@angular/forms: 4.2.4
@angular/http: 4.2.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.4
@angular/router: 4.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.1.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.4
@angular/language-service: 4.2.4
```

My steps:

1. Create new project: `ng new myProject --style=sass`
2. Install ng2-dnd: `npm install ng2-dnd --save`
3. Import *DndModule* in my *NgModule*:

---

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DndModule } from 'ng2-dnd';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DndModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4. Import *style.css* from *node_modules*

After this steps, I add a template just like at github, but with no result. I see only plain text, even with no style.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your repo to github?

Comment: where did you imported style?

Comment: I imported style in angular-cli.json,
here is my code: https://github.com/pawelidziak/my-todo-list

Comment: Does the drag-and-drop functionality work?  In other words, is the only problem the lack of styling?

Answer (score 2):

you should import style in angular-cli.json

```
 "styles": [
        "../node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css",
      ],
```